# Issue with numpy.load

Tags: python, numpy

First, I saved a NumPy array by the following command:

```
filename = 'D:\Data\\my_folder\\mydata.npy'
with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
     np.save(filename, numpy_array, allow_pickle=True, fix_imports=True)
```

The file is saved in the correct location.

Then, I tried to read it by

```
filename = 'D:\Data\\my_folder\\mydata.npy'
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
     numpy_array = np.load(filename, allow_pickle=True, fix_imports=True)
```

However, it raised the following error:

```
UnpicklingError: Failed to interpret file 'D:\\Data\\my_folder\\mydata.npy' as a pickle
```

I was wondering if somebody could help me to fix this issue.

Comment: When using `with` use `np.save(file, ...)`, not `filename`.

Comment: Try adding encoding & let me know `numpy_array = np.load(filename, allow_pickle=True, fix_imports=True, encoding='latin1') `

Comment: @hpaulj, great catch!  By using `filename` instead of `file` in the `save` and `load`, you've got the file opened twice simultaneously.  Sees very likely the file is going to be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [`.save`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [`.load`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) documentation, a **simple filepath string** will get the job done, and save the potential corruption. There is really no need to use a context manager to create the file *object*.

For example:

```
# Create and save.
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
np.save('3x3.npy', a, allow_pickle=True)

# Load array.
a_ = np.load('3x3.npy', allow_pickle=True)
```

Output `a`:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Output `a_`:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

---

Documentation excerpts:

`.save`

> Parameters: file: file, **str**, or pathlib.Path
> File or filename to which the data is saved. ...

`.load`

> Parameters: file: file-like object, **string**, or pathlib.Path
> The file to read. ...